# Keep last selected tab selected after redirecting the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I keep the last selected tab as selected after redirecting to another page and then coming back? For me the first tab is selected as default after redirecting in ruby on rails.

Answer (score 1):

Using Bootstrap 3 tabbed content markup as an example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#overview" data-toggle="tab">Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="#foo" data-toggle="tab">Debug</a></li>
  <li><a href="#stats" data-toggle="tab">Latest Usage Data</a></li>
  <li><a href="#ips" data-toggle="tab">IP Addresses</a></li>
</ul>
```

Insert this Jquery:

```
$(function(){
  if(location.hash != null){
    $("[href=" + location.hash + "]").click();
  };
});
```

Access #foo with the standard syntax for a named anchor.

```
http://example.com/wigets/3#foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using Javascript and with JQuery you can say:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabs-element").trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how how you manage your tabs, simply passing the name of the anchor in the URL might be enough (.e.g #my-tab).

Typically, this works with the tabs from Twitter Bootstrap.